# My program is crashing when it calls `strcpy()'

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str1 = "Bangladesh Bogus Party";
    char *str2 = "Sad is a beautiful Country";

    strcpy(str1 + 11, str2 + 4);
    strcat(str1, "! !! !!!");
    printf("\n%s", str1);

    return 0;
}
```

In the code blocks ,it has found....

```
-------------- Build: Debug in catcpy (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Target is up to date.
Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).


-------------- Run: Debug in catcpy (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: E:\Sobar Jonno C (Niton)\String\catcpy\bin\Debug\catcpy.exe
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "E:\Sobar Jonno C (Niton)\String\catcpy\bin\Debug\catcpy.exe"  (in E:\Sobar Jonno C (Niton)\String\catcpy\.)
```

Comment: Do not attempt to modify string literals.

Comment: gcc is a compiler; it will not run a program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't overwrite your `str1` pointer to a [string literal because they are read only memory](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294748/why-are-c-string-literals-read-only) and your program is trying to write to the memory the pointer points to which causes *Undefined Behavior* most of the time it causes a *Segmentation Fault*. And even worst you can't concatenate without previously allocating the necessary space.

If you want your code to work, you need something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str1[42] = "Bangladesh Bogus Party";
    const char *str2 = "Sad is a beautiful country";

    strcpy(str1 + 11, str2 + 4);
    strcat(str1, "! !! !!!");

    printf("%s\n", str1);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `str1` is no longer a string literal, whil `str2` is. That is because `str2` is never modified, and I added the `const` specifier to prevent from accidentally doing it. It's impossible to completely prevent this but `const` can help you notice when you do it unintentionally.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that `str1` points to a string literal.  These live in a read-only section of memory, so attempting to change them will typically cause your program to crash.  Rather than defining `str1` as a pointer, define it as an array initialized with the literal in question:

```
char str1[] = "Bangladesh Bogus Party";
```

If you do this, however, the array doesn't have enough room for the extra characters to be added.  So make the array larger so that is has enough space:

```
char str1[50] = "Bangladesh Bogus Party";
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` and `strcat` both require that the first operand points to memory that is both writable and big enough to hold the result.

In your case neither of these requirements is fulfilled.

String literals are often placed in write-protected memory by the compiler. `gcc` places string literals in write-protected memory. Other compilers can do it differently.

The problem can be solved by creating `str1` in writable memory and increasing its size so that it is big enough to hold the entire string.

The resulting string will be 41 characters + 1 for the string terminator.

Here are a couple of different ways to do it:

```
char str1[42] = "Bangladesh Bogus Party";  // Declare str1 as an array
```

or

```
char *str1 = malloc(42);                 // Allocate str1 dynamically
strcpy(str1, "Bangladesh Bogus Party");  // and copy the string to it
```

or

```
char *str1 = strdup("Bangladesh Bogus Party"); // Allocate str1 dynamically and copy the string to it. It will only be just big enough to hold the initial data
str1 = realloc(str1, 42);  // Increase the size to 42.
```